# Python program for NSlookup result

Tags: python, sockets, nslookup

I want to build a Python program to check the `NSlookup` result.

In my program, I want to output like:-

- If I input `google` then it will show “not unique” as output, but
- when I provide input like `Rajat` then the output will be unique because `rajat.com` is not a valid site (**invalid URL no IP is linked with this URL**)

Below is my code.in this code will show not unique when I input google but throw an error when I input `Rajat`.

So I just want to know how to handle this error or how we can get the output as unique when the program throws an error.

```
import socket

dns=input("Enter DNS:  ")
result= socket.gethostbyname(dns+".com")
if not result:
    print("Unique")
else:
    print("Not Unique")
```

Comment: Rajat.com has address 72.52.179.174. Use something else. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `try`-`except` to catch an error. In this code snippet we try to connect to the given domain and if the connection is successful (the website exists) it prints `Not unique`, if not, it prints `Unique`.

```py
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
dns = input("Enter DNS:  ")
try:
    s.connect((dns + ".com", 80))
except Exception as e:
    print("Unique")
else:
    print("Not unique")
```

Comment: **1.** Your code does something else (OP didn't need that some website exists, they performed only a DNS lookup, while you try HTTP connection). —  **2.** Catching Exception is not a very good thing — it catches ALL exceptions, giving for all of them the uniform message `Unique`. — But for a beginner it is not so bad answer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The `gethostbyname()` function raises the `socket.gaierror` exception if the given hostname is not found, so you have an opportunity to catch it and perform what you want:

```
import socket

dns=input("Enter DNS:  ")

try:
    result= socket.gethostbyname(dns + ".com")
except socket.gaierror:
    print("Unique")
else:
    print("Not Unique"))
```

---

*Note:*

In my humble opinion the better messages would be something as *“Not used” / “Used”* or
*“Not found” / “Found”.* Yours are a little confusing.

Comment: Consider adding an explanation to your code.

Comment: Thanks for your advice — it was a good one, so I followed it.

Comment: You're welcome. Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)